# What consumes laptop battery when it is turned off?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery-life

My Toshiba laptop consumes battery while it is off. At night I usually turn it off and unplug the power supply.

I noticed that when I turn it on again the battery is no longer full but around 90%. Once I left it off for a week and the battery was flat.

I wanted to test if it was the battery that was discharging passively or if it was the laptop that was consuming power when off, so I removed the battery from the laptop and reconnected it before turning on. The battery was at around 99%. So could be consuming battery power while the laptop is off?

Comment: It depends on your laptop model and/or the power plan for battery as configured in your particular OS. But it could very well be passive discharging (or temporal capacity loss), too. Amongst other things, the actual capacity of the battery depends on temperature. Having 99% of stored energy when you kept the battery separate from the laptop could possibly be due to keeping the battery at a place which is significantly warmer than where you keep your laptop...

Comment: When I did the experiment of removing the battery, i kept both next to each other but you made me think that when I turn the laptop off it is relatively warm due to use and when I turn on it is colder so a part of the issue could be temperature difference.

Answer (score 2):

It surely is not battery discharging, it is well known that removing the battery allows it to conserve its charge longer. Some manufacturers (Toshiba) even suggest doing so on a regular basis.

There are at least two reasons power is consumed in a pc even when it is shut off: one is that some services are not interrupted, like the clock. Also, many modern pcs can be awakened by a network event (Wake-On-Lan or even Wake on Wifi), which implies they must be mnitoring the network for such signals.

The other reason is that current Windows pcs do not really shut off, in order to allow shorter boot-up times. They are indeed in sleep mode, in which they do consume some power in order to preserve RAM, and to respond to wake-up events. These include activity of mouse, keyboard, or the pressing of power-up buttons. To this you must add Wake-On-Lan or Wake on Wifi events, and the ensuing monitoring.

By removing the battery, all of this activity, and the toll it takes on it, of course ceases.

Comment: I mostly agree (although the laptop going into standby is just a guess, albeit a reasonable one), one minor correction (yes, i am nitpicking ;). The RTC (clock) has its own little battery or super cap, both in laptops as well as on regular PC mainboards. Still, the power the RTC requires is insignificant here (how often do you change the battery on your digital wristwatch?)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and not Windows but that should not do any difference because I'm not talking about keeping it on standby.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your pc is completely turned off by selecting Shutdown, and not Sleep. Some people think as long as I press the power Button and the screen turns off then the laptop is happily off, but their mistaken and in a day or 2 the battery is flat (especially on Sleep). This is because on Sleep, most of the hardware is turned off while the RAM is left on to facilitate quick resuming (that's why Wakes are much quicker than Boots). RAM uses quite a bit of power even during Sleep.

Alternatively, it might be usb devices connected to your laptop that's drawing some power from it. Ensure you disconnect all devices when your laptop is off.